# Adding result for each attempt in Java

Tags: java

I'm completely new to Java and need some help. I'm trying to add results for each attempt in a competition but I got stuck. So far I have the first part that works but without any results added and then I tried to find a way to add results while counting allowed attempts (which are different for each discipline) but without success. What would be the best way both to count attempts and to add results for each attempt?`

```
private void addResult() {

    System.out.print("Enter the number of the participant you would like to add results for: ");
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    while (number < 0) {  
        System.out.println("Error: must be greater than or equal to zero!");
        number = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
     }
System.out.print("Enter the name of the event you would like to see results for: ");
String event = scan.nextLine();

Participant p = findParticipantByNumber(number);
Event e = findEventByName(event);

if (p == null) {
    System.out.println("No participant with number " + number + " found!");

    } else if (e == null) {
        System.out.println("No event called " + event + " found!");
    } else {

         System.out.print("Results for " + p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName() +
         " from " + p.getTeam() +
         " in " + e.getEventName() + ":" + " " + p.getResult() ); 
         scan.nextLine(); 
         Result r = new Result(e, p);
         p.addResult(r);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the counting for allowed attempts?

Comment: I think mingling user interaction with logic like this is a limiting design.  I would say a better way would be to decouple the two.  It looks like you should have a separate method for finding an event by name or id.  I'd break that out, test it separately, and leave the user interaction out of the method.

Answer (score 0):

I would store a HashMap of attempts as an instance variable in the Participant class, where the keys are Strings representing the events and the value corresponding to each key is the number of attempts so far for that event. You could call this map `attemptsByEvent` and have getter and setter methods for it in Participant. If you need, you can take a look at [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm) from TutorialsPoint about how to create and populate maps, and what they are.

You should also make a map that is accessible from within addResult() which has Strings representing the events as keys and the maximum allowed attempt for that event as the values. You could call this map `attemptMaximums`.

Then, you can modify your final block of code to check the number of attempts so far before adding the result. You should also increment the value in the Participant's map if you do add results for an attempt.

```
else {
     System.out.print("Results for " + p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName() +
         " from " + p.getTeam() +
         " in " + e.getEventName() + ":" + " " + p.getResult() ); 
     scan.nextLine(); 
     Result r = new Result(e, p);
     int attempts = p.getAttemptsByEvent().get(e);
     if(attempts < attemptMaximums.get(e)){
         p.addResult(r);
         p.getAttemptsByEvent().put(e, attempts+1);
     }
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please consider accepting it, so that others can find the information more easily.